# cannot use List<Future<?>> in method parameter when called from different places

Tags: java, list, generics

In my code I have multiple instances of `List<Future<something>>` and I wanted to have a single method that handles the wait for them to complete. But I get a compiler exception telling me that `actual argument List<Future<Boolean>> cannot be converted to List<Future<?>>`.

This is the method head:

```
public void waitForIt(<List<Future<?>> params)
```

and this is how it is called:

```
...
List<Future<Boolean>> actions = new ArrayList<Future<Boolean>>();
waitForIt(actions); <-- compiler error here
...
```

I need this to work for `List<Future<Map<String, String>>>` and several other as well.

Comment: List<Future<? extends Object>>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
public <T> void waitForIt(List<Future<T>> params)
```

as `Future<Boolean>` is not extension of `Future<?>`

http://ideone.com/tFECPN

Comment: I like this one better than my answer, I deleted my original one. Thank you.

Comment: "as Future<Boolean> is not extension of Future<?>" what does this mean? `Future<Boolean>` is a subtype of `Future<?>`

Comment: it was referring to other answer which has been deleted

Comment: for future readers: the answer that was referenced was: `public <T extends Future<?>> void waitForIt(List<T> params)`

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
public void waitForIt(List<? extends Future<?>> params)
```

When you have `List<A>` and `List<B>`, A and B must *match exactly*. Since `Future<Boolean>` is not exactly the same as `Future<?>`, it does not work.

`Future<Boolean>` is a subtype of `Future<?>`, but that is not enough. `List<A>` is not a subtype of `List<B>` even if A is a subtype of B.

We use a wildcard in the type parameter of `List` so that it doesn't have to match exactly.